# Subtracting a value by itself using 2's complement

Tags: binary, subtraction

Using the 2's complement method of subtraction, my result is 1111 (-1 in decimal system) whereas it should be 0 in the following case

```
  10010
 -10010
```

where both values are provided in binary.

The answer seems quite obvious but following the method of conversion of the negative value to 2's complement and then adding it does not seem to work in this case as the result seems to be 1111.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subtracting a number from itself using 2's complement means you add its 2's complement (subtracting a number is adding its 2's complement):

You need to know the word size in bits to determine 2's complemet, so let's suppose the number of bits in a word is 8. Then you have `00010010` as the original number, and `11101110` as its 2's complement. The 2's complement is the 1's complement (`11101101`) with `1` added to it.

Then adding:

```
 00010010   [original number, 18 decimal]
+11101110   [2's complement, -18 decimal]
---------
 00000000   [note: there's a 1 overflow bit]
```

Answer (score 0):

10010 in twos complement (assuming 5 bit two's complement) is -14 (-16 +2). 14 in twos complement is 01110 (2+4+8). So

```
 10010
-10010
=
 10010
+01110
=
 00000 (actually 100000, but the 1 is overflowed)
```